# How can I add missing "env import" to u-boot?

Tags: embedded, u-boot, yocto

I'm trying to set up a u-boot on an imx8 board to load environment variables from a uEnv.txt file on the first partition.  I've got it working so that it loads the file, and now I'm trying to import that data with `env import`.  However, the u-boot version built with the BSP from the vendor doesn't seem to have `env import` as an option.  This is what I get when I try and run it:

```
u-boot=> env import -t ${loadaddr} $(filesize}
env - environment handling commands

Usage:
env default [-f] -a - [forcibly] reset default environment
env default [-f] var [...] - [forcibly] reset variable(s) to their default values
env delete [-f] var [...] - [forcibly] delete variable(s)
env edit name - edit environment variable
env exists name - tests for existence of variable
env print [-a | name ...] - print environment
env run var [...] - run commands in an environment variable
env save - save environment
env set [-f] name [arg ...]
```

I've also noticed some other missing commands that I'm used to like `loadfat`.

Is `env import` something optional that needs to be configured before compiling?  If so, can anyone provide information on how that is done?

For reference, I'm using Yocto Sumo to build u-boot, and the u-boot version number shows as: U-Boot SPL 2018.03-imx_v2018.03_4.14.78_1.0.0_ga_var01+g5c48b6c (Oct 29 2019 - 13:16:16 +0000)

Edit: I actually can't find reference to `env import` being an official command, but I've seen reference to it in several places.  If it's not a command, how can I take environment variables that I've loaded from a file in to memory, and apply them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable `CONFIG_CMD_IMPORTENV`.

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a try.  Is it documented somewhere what the various CONFIG_ options are and what they do?

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks!